# REGEX to check for phrase within first 25 characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regular expressions to match a keyword. Is it possible to check for this keyword within ONLY the first 25 characters?

For example, I want to find `"APPLE"`:

`'Johnny picked an APPLE from the tree'` - Match Found (within first 25 chars)

`'Johnny picked something from a tree that had an APPLE'` - Not Found (because APPLE does not exist within the first 25 chars).

Is there syntax for this?

Comment: Can't you just run the regex on the first 25 characters? What was it in Python, `s[:25]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution would be to [slice](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) off the 25 first characters and then do the regex matching.

```
myString = 'Johnny picked an APPLE from the tree'
slicedString = myString[:25]
# do regex matching on slicedString
```

Comment: sometimes the simplest is the best (IMO)

Comment: @GarethDavis It **is** the best, there should be one way to do it!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. You prefix your keyword with zero to 25 - length(keyword) "any" characters.

I'm not sure if this is actual python syntax, but the RE should be `^.{0,20}APPLE`.

Edit: for clarification

- `^.{0,20}APPLE` should be used when looking for a substring. Use this in Python.
- `.{0,20}APPLE.*` should be used when matching the whole string.

Another edit: Apparently Python only has substring mode, so the `^` anchor is necessary.

Comment: You want the `^` if you're doing `re.search`, not necessary if doing `re.match`. The trailing `.*` isn't necessary in any case unless you want to match the rest of the line for some reason.

Comment: That will not work. You can't check the length of matched part in a regular expression. What you write is only: *from 0 to 20 any symbols*

Comment: What I write is 0 to 20 any symbols followed by the 5 letter keyword. That is the same as the keyword anywhere in the first 25 characters. (Maybe you missed the update; at first I didn't anchor the expression correctly (^xxx) or (xxx.*)).

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [slice](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) on your string:

```
>>> import re
>>> string1 = "Johnny picked an APPLE from the tree"
>>> string2 = "Johnny picked something from a tree that had an APPLE"
>>> re.match(".*APPLE.*", string1[:25])  # Match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2364030>
>>> re.match(".*APPLE.*", string2[:25])  # Does not match
```

Comment: I don't see the need for the starting and trailing `.*` when you are just looking for a match on `'APPLE'`

Comment: re.match('APPLE', ...) will match only if the word APPLE is at the beginning of the string ; re.match('.*APPLE', ...) will works. In fact, the better way is to use re.search() instead of re.match(). -- REF: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match